# Typescript is failing to infer keyof T where T is defined in an outer scope generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This code snippet highlights the issue I am having:

```js
type Bar = {
    prop: string,
    numProp: number
}

type Other = {
    prop: number,
    strProp: string
}

type Foo<T> = {
    func: <P extends keyof T>(propName: P, propValue: T[P]) => T;
}

const init = <T>(): Foo<T> => {
    return {func: <P extends keyof T>(propName: P, propValue: T[P]): T => { return {} as T }};
}

let foobar: Foo<Bar> = init<Bar>();

//This should work but does not:
const res1 = foobar.func('prop', 'hello');
//Error: Argument type "prop" is not assignable to parameter type keyof T 
//Error: Argument type "hello" is not assignable to parameter type Bar[keyof T]

const res2: Bar = foobar.func('prop', 'hello');
//Valid

const res3 = foobar.func<keyof Bar>('prop', 'hello');
//Valid

const res4: Other = foobar.func('prop', 'hello');
//Error: Initializer type Bar is not assignable to variable type Other 

const res5 = foobar.func<keyof Other>('prop', 'hello');
//Valid: illogical though.

const res6 = foobar.func<keyof Other>('prop', 5);
//Error: Argument type 5 is not assignable to parameter type Bar[keyof Bar]

const res7 = foobar.func<keyof Other>('strProp', 'hello');
//Error: Argument type "strProp" is not assignable to parameter type keyof Bar

const res8: Bar = foobar.func('prop', 5);
//Error: Argument type 5 is not assignable to parameter type Bar["prop"] 

const res9 = foobar.func<keyof Bar>('prop', 5);
//Valid
```

The function `init` specifies the generic type `T` (called with `Bar` specified). However within `func` it is unable to correctly recognise that `T` is `Bar` as far as the `keyof T` part. It is like `keyof T` does not expand to `keyof Bar`.

I can explicitly define the returned values type as `Bar` then it makes `T` in the reference of `keyof T`, `Bar`, and the code is valid, but it already knew that `T` was bar as mentioned in the second parameter error: `Argument type "hello" is not assignable to parameter type Bar[keyof T]`, where it was defined as `T[P]`, thus it's only issue seems to be through `<P extends keyof T>`.

I can also specify `P` as `keyof Bar` as shown with `res3` and it accepts this as valid. However with this one things get a little weird, as while in `res4` we correctly get an error where we try to set the returned values type to `Other` as it recognises that the return type is `Bar`, it is quite happy to accept the illogical code for `res5` where we can specify `P` to `keyof Other`, even though the return type `T` is `Bar` and yet it only allows keys of `Bar` to be used with `res6` and `res7` failing with errors. As can be seen from these errors the passed parameter type `keyof Other` is being completely ignored and it is correctly identifying that `T` is `Bar` and `P` is `keyof Bar`

Finally, while `res8` is detected correctly as invalid, `res9` is accepted even though `Bar['prop']` is `string`, not `number`. Leading me to believe that it isn't fully understanding the `keyof Bar` either.

The code above shows everything I tried, but I would expect `T` to follow into `func` as `Bar` and `P` to be understood as `extends keyof Bar`, and thus the only valid types of `P` be `prop` and `numProp` and when `func('prop'` is called, the second parameter to be of type `string` from `Bar['prop']`. Thus the following code should be valid:

```js
let foobar: Foo<Bar> = init<Bar>();
const res1 = foobar.func('prop', 'hello');
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce most of what you're seeing here](https://tsplay.dev/mxkaZN) and frankly as soon as `res1` worked as expected I stopped scrutinizing the rest, since there's clearly some disconnect here.  Are you sure this is a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @jcalz for providing me with a pointer to the solution.

This issue was with my IDE (WebStorm 2022.3.1), upgrading to the latest 2023.1 resolved my issue. Lesson here for me is to go to the TypeScript playground before spending a day on issues like this.

Thanks again